# How correctly sort a list<string> with numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I met a Difficulty to sort a list item string containing numbers.
I wish I could automatically sort from smallest to largest.
Here is my code:

```
// Initialize an array to store the numbers
List<string> tab_num = new List<string>();
tab_num.Add("A.3.2.1");
tab_num.Add("A.3.3.1");
tab_num.Add("A.1.0.1");
tab_num.OrderByDescending(num => num).ToList();
```

Why my result is false ?...

```
[1] A.3.2.1

[2] A.3.3.1

[3] A.1.0.1
```

Expected Result:

```
[1] A.1.0.1

[2] A.3.2.1

[3] A.3.3.1
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried using `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: @Richard -> Yes i have and it's the same result

Comment: Thanks you .i have just forgot tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList(); and not only tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();

Comment: I do not understand why I rotted my votes for this ... But even as thank you ^ ^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OrderByDescending means from bigger to lower.
Also you are not assigning your result after sorting.

try this:

```
        List<string> tab_num = new List<string>();
        tab_num.Add("A.3.2.1");
        tab_num.Add("A.3.3.1");
        tab_num.Add("A.1.0.1");
        tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks you i have just forgot tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList(); and not only tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();

Comment: I do not understand why I rotted my votes for this ... But even as thank you ^ ^

Answer (score 4):

Because you are sorting alphabetically. You should use `OrderBy` anyway if you want to order "smallest to largest". You need to parse it to somewhat numerical or to version:

```
Version v = null;
var ordered = tab_num.Select(tab => new { tab, Versionpart = tab.Substring(2) })
                     .Where(x => Version.TryParse(x.Versionpart, out v))
                     .OrderBy(x => v)
                     .Select(x => x.tab)
                     .ToList();
```

(assuming that the version is always found at `tab.Substring(2)`)

Comment: thanks you right but i have just forgot tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList(); and not only tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

You should set result of linq query to any variable  (and use OrderBy):

```
List<string> tab_num = new List<string>();
tab_num.Add("A.3.2.1");
tab_num.Add("A.3.3.1");
tab_num.Add("A.1.0.1");
tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();
```

`tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList()` is not perform sorting on source list, but returns sorted list.

Comment: Thanks you .i have just forgot tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList(); and not only tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need linq here, use `Sort` method:

```
tab_num.Sort();
```

But if you want to make your code work, just *assign* resulting list to a source list:

```
tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

the main problem here is that you are not assigning the result to the list as suggested below.

BTW: This list doesn't contains numbers, it contains string so the comparer uses the alphabetic comparator. you should use `OrderBy` not `OrderByDescending`. I suggest you to implement your own comparator since your strings are quite simple and the default comparator will give you wrong responses when numbers grows over 9

Comment: I have try ..but it's the same result

Comment: @Mehdi Bugnard: result just cannot be the same

Comment: Yes it can - because he doesn't assign the result of the sort operation to the list, so he outputs the original list, which is of course the same before and after sorting.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: the fact that OP doesn't assign the result somewhere doesn't mean that the result is the same.

Comment: i have just forgot tab_num = tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList(); and not only tab_num.OrderBy(num => num).ToList();

Comment: I do not understand why I rotted my votes for this ... But even as thank you ^ ^

Comment: my suggestion to implement your own comparer still remains. watch out when numbers grow

Comment: @zerkms: You're arguing technically - I'm arguing functionally. The result the OP sees is the same no matter what sort operation you use.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: if we won't discuss in a precise way - OP won't learn how to program ever. Let's not spread voodoo things about programming ;-)